# Subracting all elements of array A from all elements of B?

Tags: python, math, numpy, matrix, subtraction

I am looking for the quickest method to subtract all elements of array A, from all elements of array B. The only way I know how to do it is:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([1,2,3])
new = []
for i in a:
    new.append(b - a[i])
```

Ideally, I would like to end up with a matrix `new` which would be qual to `[0,1,2;-1,0,1;-2,-1,0]`

I would also like to extend this type of operation to Pandas timedelta series. For example, I can do this:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])
b=np.array([1,2,3])
aT = pd.to_timedelta(a,'D')
bT = pd.to_timedelta(b,'D')
new = []

for i in aT:
    x.append(bT - i)
```

and end up with this:

```
[TimedeltaIndex(['0 days', '1 days', '2 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq='D'), TimedeltaIndex(['-1 days', '0 days', '1 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq='D'), TimedeltaIndex(['-2 days', '-1 days', '0 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq='D')]
```

but that's very slow for very large arrays.
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `b` to a 2D array case with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then let [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) play its part for a fast vectorized solution, like so -

```
a - b[:,None]
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [20]: b
Out[20]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [21]: a - b[:,None]
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [-2, -1,  0]])
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this work with pandas timedelta series? For example, `df1.date - df2.date.ix[:,None]`?

Comment: @user1566200 Could you add a sample dataframe case into the question? Also, add the expected output please.

Comment: @user1566200 It doesn't look straight-forward. If you can extract the days info into NumPy arrays, you can employ the posted approach. But, I am not aware of any direct method to do so. Sorry!